# Laravel ajax 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using ajax to display notification in my laravel project.It works fine.But I got the below error in my console showing repeatedly when I'm in the **create or edit** form view(In CRUD),
And the error is,

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/laravel/movecab/public/vehicles/shownotify 500 (Internal Server Error)
 send   @   jquery.min.js:4
 ajax   @   jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   create:113
 setInterval (async)        
(anonymous) @   create:112
```

How can I solve it?
My ajax code,

```
<script>

var old_count = 0;
var i=0;
setInterval(function(){    
$.ajax({

    url : "shownotify",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
  if (data.data > old_count) 
  { 
if (i == 0)
{old_count = data.data;} 
else{
$('#notify').html(data.action + "New user");
$('#count').html(data.action );
old_count = data.data;
}
} i=1;
 }
   });
   },1000);                             
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">



$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.I've tried with that, the errors in my console has cleared,but the notification doesn't show